# java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory) - Download File

Tags: java, linux

I have Web Application hosted on Linux, contains page to upload .rar file and another page to download it. for upload function working fine and file uploaded successfully to server but for download it gives me below exception:

```
 [servelt.scriptdownloadservelt] in context with path [/OSS-CPE-Tracker] threw exception
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: \usr\local\apache-tomcat-8.5.31\OSS-CPE-Tracker\Zaky\QCAM.rar (No such file or directory)
```

I used below funcation to make upload:

```
String destDir = "/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/OSS-CPE-Tracker/Zaky";
            for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("QCAM.rar")) {
                                                
                    File destFile = new File(destDir, "QCAM.rar");
                    if (destFile.exists()) {
                        destFile.delete();
                    }
                    item.write(new File("/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/OSS-CPE-Tracker/Zaky" + File.separator + name));
                    request.setAttribute("gurumessage", "File Uploaded Successfully");

                }else {
                    request.setAttribute("gurumessage", "Kindly use the agreed name");

                }
```

and here function for download that i face issue on it and above exception appear:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String gurufile = "QCAM.rar\\";
    String gurupath = "\\usr\\local\\apache-tomcat-8.5.31\\OSS-CPE-Tracker\\Zaky";

    
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + gurufile + "\"");

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(gurupath
            + gurufile);

    int i;
    while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
    out.close();
```

Comment: `String gurufile = "QCAM.rar\\";`  ... maybe this should be `String gurufile = "QCAM.rar";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for this error is that file cannot be found under that path.

Please verify the path

```java
    String gurufile = "QCAM.rar\\";
    String gurupath = "\\usr\\local\\apache-tomcat-8.5.31\\OSS-CPE-Tracker\\Zaky";
    // <...>
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(gurupath
            + gurufile);
```

In `unix` systems file path is resolved using forward slash `/` and not a backslash `\`.

Try changing to the same value as your `upload` script:

```java
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.31/OSS-CPE-Tracker/Zaky/QCAM.rar")
```

That should do